# How to use a loop then calculate the sum of a list?

Tags: python, loops, floating-point, sum, rounding

I need to write a function "sum_reciprocals()" which takes 1 input argument, a positive integer "n", and returns 1 output value, the sum of the reciprocals of all integers from 1 to n (inclusive).
The result should be returned as a floating point number, and rounded to 5 decimal places.

here is my code

```
def sum_reciprocals(n):
    x = [1]
    n = 10000
    for i in range(2,n+1):
        x.append(x[i-2]+1/x[i-1])
    sum_reciprocals = round(sum(x))
    return sum_reciprocals
```

But it says that "IndexError: list index out of range" on my fifth line.

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `x.append(x[i-2]+1/x[i-1])`: what do you expect will be the value of `i`, the first time through the loop? Therefore, what indices will be used in order to look into `x`? What does `x` contain before the loop starts? How many values is that? Therefore, what indices are valid? What is the intended purpose of this logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't really understand what's the point of this

```
x.append(x[i - 2] + 1 / x[i - 1])
```

You can just iterate from `1` to `n` with `i` and add `1 / i` to the total sum, like so

```
def sum_reciprocals(n):
    total = 0
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        total += 1 / i

    return total
```

or using list comprehension with `sum()` function

```
def sum_reciprocals(n):
    return sum([1 / i for i in range(1, n + 1)])
```

or even adding lambda expression to this

```
 sum_reciprocals = lambda n: sum([1 / i for i in range(1, n + 1)])
```

Although last one will be a violation of PEP 8 E731 Code style standart (but it's good to know you can do that)

Answer (score 1):

Your list only has one element, but in the first iteration of the for loop you try to access the 0-th and the 1st element :)

Comment: OHHHH, you are right! Thank you very much!

Comment: @xiongshizhao no problem :) mind accepting this answer?

Comment: sure, but i can only accept it after 4min!

Comment: oh, completely forgot about that limitation sorry :P